# Splitting data in column based on a word

Tags: r, dataframe, split, strsplit

Is there a code to create a column with only the speed number? In the Cpu column, as included in the image, too much unnecessary information is included for me. I only want the ''Ghz''number (f.i. 2.3, 1.8 and 2.5).

[image]

Comment: Please use code, not graphics.. Surely you don't want each and every helper out  there to have to do this for themselves?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
library(stringr)

data %>%
  mutate(speed = as.numeric(str_extract(Cpu, "\\d*[.]?\\d+(?=GHz$)")))
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly easier regex is this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(CPU_new = str_extract(Cpu, "[0-9.]+(?=GHz)"))
```

`base R`:

```
df$CPU_new <- str_extract(df$Cpu, "[0-9.]+(?=GHz)")
```

How this works:

- `[0-9.]+`: character class allowing digits and the period occurring at least one or more times
- `(?=GHz)`: positive lookahead asserting that the match to be `extract`ed must be followed by the literal string `GHz`

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is better, but an alternative approach to using complicated regex is to extract just the 3 positions right before "GHz" using the `stringr` package:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ScreenResolution = paste("Test",LETTERS[1:3]),
                 Cpu = c("Intel Core i5 2.3GHz","Intel Core i5 1.8GHz",
                         "Intel Core i5 72000U 2.3GHz"),
                 Ram = "8GB")
```

Code:

```
library(stringr)
df$Cpu_new <- str_sub(df$Cpu, str_locate(df$Cpu, pattern = "GHz")[1]-4,
                              str_locate(df$Cpu, pattern = "GHz")[1]-1)
```

Output:

```
#   ScreenResolution                         Cpu Ram Cpu_new
# 1           Test A        Intel Core i5 2.3GHz 8GB     2.3
# 2           Test B        Intel Core i5 1.8GHz 8GB     1.8
# 3           Test C Intel Core i5 72000U 2.3GHz 8GB     2.3
```

If you wanted it to be numeric, use `as.numeric(str_sub(...))`